# How to screen record a rolling n-second window

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder, screen-recording, web-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I'm aware of the [`MediaRecorder API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) and how to record screen/audio/video, and then download those recordings. I'm also aware of npm modules such as [`react-media-recorder`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media-recorder) that leverage that API.

I would like to record a rolling n-second window of screen recording, to allow the user to create clips and then be able to share those clips. I cannot record the entire session as I don't know how long they will last, meaning I don't know how big the recordings might get (I assume there is a limit to what the recording can have in memory.)

Is there any easy way to use `MediaRecorder` to record a rolling window (i.e. to always have in memory the last 30 seconds recorded)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent quite a while trying to make this work. Unfortunately, the only solution that works for me involves making 30 recorders.

The naive solution to this problem is to call `recorder.start(1000)` to record data in one second intervals, then maintain a circular buffer on the `dataavailable` event. The issue with this is that `MediaRecorder` supports a very, very limited number of encodings. None of these encodings allow data packets to be dropped from the beginning, since they contain important metadata. With better understanding of the protocols, I'm sure that it is to some extent possible to make this strategy work. However, simply concatenating the packets together (when some are missing) does not create a valid file.

Another attempt I made used two `MediaRecorder` objects at once. One of them would record second-long start packets, and the other would record regular data packets. When taking a clip, this then combined a start packet from the first recorder with the packets from the second. However, this usually resulted in corrupted recordings.

This solution is not fantastic, but it does work: the idea is to keep 30 `MediaRecorder` objects, each offset by one second. For the sake of this demo, the clips are 5 seconds long, not 30:

```html
<canvas></canvas><button>Clip!</button>

<style>
   canvas, video, button {
      display: block;
   }
</style>

<!-- draw to the canvas to create a stream for testing -->
<script>
   const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   // fill background with white
   ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

   // randomly draw stuff
   setInterval(() => {
      const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
      const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
      const radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.stroke();
   }, 100);
</script>

<!-- actual recording -->
<script>
   // five second clips
   const LENGTH = 5;

   const codec = 'video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus'
   const stream = canvas.captureStream();

   // circular buffer of recorders
   let head = 0;
   const recorders = new Array(LENGTH)
      .fill()
      .map(() => new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: codec }));

   // start them all
   recorders.forEach((recorder) => recorder.start());

   let data = undefined;
   recorders.forEach((r) => r.addEventListener('dataavailable', (e) => {
      data = e.data;
   }));

   setInterval(() => {
      recorders[head].stop();
      recorders[head].start();

      head = (head + 1) % LENGTH;
   }, 1000);

   // download the data
   const download = () => {
      if (data === undefined) return;
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(data);

      // download the url
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.download = 'test.webm';
      a.href = url;
      a.click();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
   };

   // stackoverflow doesn't allow downloads
   // we show the clip instead
   const show = () => {
      if (data === undefined) return;
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(data);

      // display url in new video element
      const v = document.createElement('video');
      v.src = url;
      v.controls = true;
      document.body.appendChild(v);
   };

   document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', show);
</script>
```

Comment: Heh, I was afraid this might be the answer :) Thank you so much for showing a good way to implement this and talking about the codecs, that makes a lot of sense and wasn't something I had considered. I'll leave the question open for 24H but will accept this otherwise. Thanks so much for the time

Comment: I wonder, what do you think of this code (grep for `timeSlice`)? It's unclear to me if this is doing what I'm looking for since I haven't tried it out yet, but I wonder if you might see a path based on it (or maybe it is doing what we are looking for): https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/7b1c360f27c7ae34047137bb2356e39b6f93374f/dev/MediaStreamRecorder.js

Comment: @MatthewHerbst From what I can tell, that isn't going to be too helpful. Keep in mind that concatenating blobs IS okay, but the blobs need to be consecutive and there cannot be any missing in the beginning. In their case, they do concatenate blobs retrieved on an interval, but they also don't drop any, which is what we would like to do.